# Cordova 5.4.0 causing google is not defined on Android but not iOS

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to upgrade my existing app from Cordova 4.x to Cordova 5.4. I've had no problem updating it in the past, but this time, I'm seeing the following error when I try to startup my app:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined"
```

My declaration remains unchanged in my index.html and this is near the top of call my JS declarations. Any idea?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/sencha-touch/sencha-touch-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

I verified that my config.xml and the correct cordova.js is being copied into the `/www` directory of my Android app (per an earlier posted soln), but still get this error.  The same upgraded app works fine on iOS with all the Google Maps functionality.

Comment: probably you don't have the whitelist correctly configured, so you can't download the google js and google is not defined

Comment: No, I've had that set wide open for awhile using `<access origin="*" />`. Again this works fine for iOS and previous versions.

Comment: Origin * is not enough, read the whitelist doc again, things change. Cordova ios is on version 3.x.x and cordova android is on 4.x.x, they don't work on the same way

Comment: Great...if you have an answer post below and I'll credit you with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems with Cordova 4.0.0+ for Android you have to install the [cordova-whitelist-plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) and add this to your config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />

<!-- Wildcards are allowed for the protocol, as a prefix
     to the host, or as a suffix to the path -->
<allow-intent href="https://*.example.com/*" />

<allow-navigation href="*://*/*" />
```